# c# - \r\n string not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

I have this string below:

```
<List>\r\n  <First>\r\n    <Second>BlaBla..</Second>\r\n...
```

But in View (MVC Asp.Net) presenting in one line only.
What can I do to respect the \r\n to broke in a new line?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the other answers that suggest using `<br/>`, you can also use the CSS white-space property which can actually make line breaks when it sees `\r\n`, or the `<pre>` tag which has this set up by default. See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 4):

`\r\n` will format your string in source, it will be visible when you view HTML source of your page. You need to use HTML `<br>` tag instead of `\r\n`, so your browser will format your output accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your view is an HTML page rendered in the browser, understand that HTML does not render line break characters. The source code will, but not the HTML. If you need line breaks, you should use a tag structure that renders them, such as `<p>` or `<br>`.